# Show internal structure of an R object

Tags: r, serialization, data-structures

Is there a way to show the *complete* internal structure of an R object in an unambiguous and human readable way?

The `str` function doesn't exactly do this, as it shows custom representations.  For example, applying it to an igraph object gives something like

```
IGRAPH U--- 3 3 -- Full graph
+ attr: name (g/c), loops (g/x)
+ edges:
[1] 1--2 1--3 2--3
```

This is nice and readable, but it's specific to igraph objects (it's clear that it uses a custom formatting for them).  I'm looking for something general.  I found `dput`, and for a while I thought that this provides complete information.  The same igraph object is shown as

```
structure(list(3, FALSE, c(1, 2, 2), c(0, 0, 1), c(0, 1, 2), 
    c(0, 1, 2), c(0, 0, 1, 3), c(0, 2, 3, 3), list(c(1, 0, 1), 
        structure(list(name = "Full graph", loops = FALSE), .Names = c("name", 
        "loops")), list(), list())), class = "igraph")
```

But then I read about pairlists in the R Language Definition and I noticed that  `dput(pairlist(1,2))` gives `list(1,2)`.  The information that we started with a pairlist is gone.

So is there something similar to `dput` that shows the internal structure of an R object and gives *complete* information about it?  (The main reason I want this is that it would help me understand the structure of R objects better.)

If there isn't, how would I query an R object to get enough information about it (in a human readable way---not machine readable) to be able to reconstruct it completely?

Comment: How about `.Internal(inspect(foo))`?

Comment: I think `dput` *is* what you want and the `pairlist` exception is just that - an exception. As far as I understand you're not supposed to use `pairlist`'s, so the issue of `dput`'ing it is a bit moot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @eddi, why don't you put that as an answer?

Comment: I read in your `dput` output in and `str`-ed it. I got the standard output for a list with an extra class. I guess you're getting something different because igraphs come from some package. I wonder if there's something like `base::str` (which doesn't exist) that you can use here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have much more to add besides my comment, so this is just for completeness for future generations :)

`dput` *is* doing what you want. With rare exceptions, one of them being `pairlist` (I assume there might be other exceptions as well, but I don't actually know what they are), it will not be exactly the same object, but, at least in the case of `pairlist` there is a reason for that. Since `pairlist` is not supposed to be used outside of internal code, the output of `dput` can be considered to be doing the user a favor by converting an internal object into the *equivalent* external one.

Comment: There are more exceptions. Environments are `dput`'ed simply as "<environment>", even if they have attributes. Closures lose `srcref` attributes, the enclosing environment and the bytecode (if present).

Answer (score 2):

`dput` is a somewhat disappointing solution, as the result is very messy. (It is, however, better than what I was doing before.)

I'd suggest (1) `dput`, (2) make a copy, (3) assign the base class to the result (as seen in the `dput`) and (4) `str` it.

In this case:

```
> x<-dput(my_graph)
structure(list(3, FALSE, c(1, 2, 2), c(0, 0, 1), c(0, 1, 2), 
c(0, 1, 2), c(0, 0, 1, 3), c(0, 2, 3, 3), list(c(1, 0, 1), 
    structure(list(name = "Full graph", loops = FALSE), .Names = c("name", 
    "loops")), list(), list())), class = "igraph")
> class(x)<-"list"
> str(x)
List of 9
 $ : num 3
 $ : logi FALSE
 $ : num [1:3] 1 2 2
 $ : num [1:3] 0 0 1
 $ : num [1:3] 0 1 2
 $ : num [1:3] 0 1 2
 $ : num [1:4] 0 0 1 3
 $ : num [1:4] 0 2 3 3
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ : num [1:3] 1 0 1
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ name : chr "Full graph"
  .. ..$ loops: logi FALSE
  ..$ : list()
  ..$ : list()
```

Comment: I haven't used `dput` before, so I don't know how general this approach is. This is basically the same solution @eddi gave, but with some new steps. I learned a lot from his answer and the comments above. What I've written here was just too long to be a comment on his answer, which is already good enough. I hope someone comes along with a more satisfying answer, though. (I starred the question.) `.Internal(inspect())` (which @Joshua Ulrich mentioned) might be the next best thing, but I'm not yet programmer enough to read that output at a glance.