How to remove method from an R class?
The foodwebr package redefines str() method for its class
> str(x)
A `foodweb`:  3 vertices and 3 edges 
> methods(class="foodweb")
[1] as.character as.matrix    plot         print        str          summary

That's a bad practice, wouldn't you agree? str() is supposed to show the internal data structure, it shouldn't be redefined? The ?str help itself says "Compactly display the internal structure of an R object", and this redefined method is preventing it!
So, how do I deactivate this method, to allow the default str() to take place? I tried the following, but with no success:
removeMethod("str", "foodweb")
str.foodweb <- NULL

I also tried to skip the class-specific method and to call directly the masked one, but no success:
utils::str(x) # still calls the class-specific method


It's not a bad practice at all, since str from the utils package is a generic function and actually it's a good practice to define a method for custom classes. In the utils package different methods are written for data frames, Date objects and other classes. It's not intended to inspect the internal structure; rather it shows what who develops the API wants the user to see.

@nicola I use the str function when I want to inspect the internal data structure. That's how I understand this purpose. Not "what the developer wants me to see". That's what print() or summary() is for. PS: see the ?str help, it says "compactly display the internal structure of an R object".

I agree it can be a bit of a pain if str doesn't work as expected (or as one expects) but this behaviour is far from unique: see methods(str) for several methods. Anyway, to use normal str you can use utils:::str.default(fw)

In any case, it's pretty standard for custom classes to define their str method. Think about R objects that are external pointers to C/C++ structures: the internal R structure couldn't give any info on the object and redefining str is very useful.

BTW, the "shouldn't be redefined" is wrong: if so, the R team wouldn't have made it generic.

I should also clarify my first comment. It's more correct to say that str is not a universal function that allows to inspect the internal structure of any R object, since this is not possible. Rather, it's intended for that purpose, but it's up to who develops the API to conform to that.

Likely relevant/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366733/show-internal-structure-of-an-r-object

@nicola related, thanks, but just the title of my question suggests it's definitely not a duplicate.

@user20650 Many thanks! I am just waiting if someone comes up with something different, but this is definitely a valid answer.
